# How can I set chosen font in textview

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I have a question. How Can I set font for example: Harrington in textview. I use:

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromFile("C:/Fonts/Kokila.ttf");
gameResult.setTypeface(type);
gameResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
```

but this solution is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: aren' you supposed to set the font after you findviewbyid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first place your font in assets folder then like:

[image]

```
gameResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Kokila.ttf"); 
gameResult.setTypeface(type);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the font from your PC! Your phone does not have access to the 'C:/' drive of your PC, and therefore cannot load the font. You need to place the Font into the Assets folder of your application, and then read it from there.

You can read a file from the Assets folder using

```
context.getAssets().open(fileName);
```